# Append div after every items in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i need to create some button dependenly from my array, in this mode i create in my view:

```
<button  ng-repeat=...../>
```

but i would have a div after every items, i dont think is correct to insert into button , and for this i try to move to out. But if i create a div outer my button  with ng repeat :
like :

```
<div ng-repeat>
   <button ..../>
   <div ..../>
</div>
```

the layout seeems broken.
How i can solve?
thanks

Comment: It would be nice if you provide a working plunker or codepen with layout and styles included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, it looks like you want to use the `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` directives, to define the start and end of the group of elements that should be repeated.

```
<button ng-repeat-start="item in items" />
<div ng-repeat-end />
```

[See docs here for details.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points)

Answer (score 0):

try this remove div

```
<input type ="button" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-value="item.value"/>
```